# How to pass null as a field's initial value in react-final-form?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-final-form

A custom React component I use inside a `react-final-form` `<Field>` has a value prop of `int?`. Its value can either be an integer or null. But when I set a `null` initial value for this field component's value using the `initialValues` prop of the `<Form>` component, `react-final-form` converts the `null` to an empty string `''`.

I know I can easily work around this by creating a wrapper component that checks for `''` and converts it to `null`, but is there some other cleaner way to fix this?  Or is this a library bug?

https://codesandbox.io/s/yq00zxn271

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";

const IntField = (props) => (
  <span>
    <input type="text" value={props.value === null ? 0 : props.value} />
    <pre>
      <b>props.{props.name} === null</b> : {(initialValues[props.name] === null).toString()}
      <br />
      <b>props.value === null</b> : {((isNull) => (<span style={{ color: isNull ? 'green' : 'red' }}>{isNull.toString()}</span>))(props.value === null)}
      <br />
      <b>props: </b>{JSON.stringify(props)}
      <br />
      <b>initialValues: </b>{JSON.stringify(initialValues)}
    </pre>
  </span>
)

const onSubmit = values => {
  console.log('submitted')
}

const initialValues = { someInteger: null };

const App = () => (
    <Form
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      render={() => (
        <form>
          <label>Some Integer:</label>&nbsp;
          <Field name="someInteger">
            {({ input, meta }) => (
              <IntField {...input} />
            )}
          </Field>
        </form>
      )}
    />
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `<Field>` prop [allowNull?](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#allownull-boolean) to turn off this behavior so that null values will be passed as-is to the child component.

Like this:

```
<Field name="someInteger1" allowNull={true}>
  {({ input, meta }) => (
    <IntField {...input} />
  )}
</Field>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/n4rl2j5n04

*(answering my own question as a help for others, since it took me a while to figure out what was going on and how to fix it)*

Comment: Yep. You got it! 

Answer (score 6):

If you are like me and was looking for a way to prevent final-form from undefine-ing empty strings, you can use [parse](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps#parse) with identity function:

```
<Field
  name="myField"
  parse={x => x}
  component={TextField}
/>
```